# One submit button, new window and new page in same tab

Tags: javascript, windows, forms

I've been working at this for hours but can't figure it out. I have a submit button on my site. When someone presses the submit button I would like a new window to open as well as the page to open to a new page. This is what I have so far. It opens the current page to what I want but does not open a new window. Can someone assist me with cleaning this up to get it to work correctly? Thank you.

```
<form id="header-box-form" action="” method="get">

<input type="text" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)" maxlength="10"   size="16" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" tabindex="1">
<input onmouseover="this.src='http://www.annuitiesrates.org/pictures/orng_btn02.png';"

   onmouseout="this.src='http:// www.annuitiesrates.org /pictures/orng_btn01.png';"

   onclick="newWindow('https://quotes.usinsuranceonline.com/annuitycontact.php','window2');window.open('http:// www.annuitiesrates.org/test.html','_self',' ')"

                          src="http:// www.annuitiesrates.org/pictures/orng_btn01.png"
                          type="image">

</form>
```

Comment: You need to do three things: format your code properly, describe your problem, and retag your question.

Comment: I am not sure how to format the code. I am an extreme newbie at this. I pieced this code together through various searches. I added to the question to clarify the problem (the "new window" portion of the code doesn't work) and I added a couple more tags. Thanks